# submenu with tippyJS in NuxtJS application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Im trying to create a menu [like this](https://codepen.io/fabswt/pen/rXVVqP) in my NuxtJS app.
I use NuxtJS `v2.17.0` together with `vue-tippy` `4.16.1` ([see package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tippy))

I've got this now:
[image]

Which works great (styling to be done).
The first button is a `<nuxt-link>`, so that works. However, the second item is a button that should trigger a delete confirmation modal on the same page. In my `.vue` file I have a `method` called `deleteOrder()` that should be triggered, im not able to get this to work.

At the moment I have this in my template:

```js
<ul :id="'tippy-menu-' + order.id" class="list-unstyled d-flex flex-column m-0">
      <li class="align-items-center d-flex p-2 cursor-pointer">
        <nuxt-link :to="localePath({ name: 'orders-edit', params: { id: order.id } })">
          <i class="fa fa-search me-2"></i>
          {{ $t('View') }}
        </nuxt-link>
      </li>
      <li class="align-items-center d-flex p-2 cursor-pointer" @click="deleteOrder">
        <i class="fa fa-trashcan me-2 text--systemred"></i>
        {{ $t('Delete') }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

And on component mounted, I have this:

```js
  mounted() {
    const el = document.getElementById('tippy-menu-' + this.order?.id)
    if (el) {
      this.menuHtml = el.outerHTML
    }
  },
```

It makes sense to me that the `@click="deleteOrder"` part is not 'copied' to the html of the tippy but I have no clue on how to do this otherwise. Replacing it with `onclick="deleteOrder"` does not work either as it gives back a `Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteOrder is not defined` in the chrome console when clicked....